# Дополнительный текст для каждой точки

Tags: javascript, диаграммы, google-chart

Использую google charts для графиков. Код такой:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Сумма');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Процент');
    data.addRows([
        ['267.78', 0.5],
        ['269.12', 0.5],
        ['284.98', 0],
        ['285', 0],
        ['286.42', 0.502],
        ['303.26', 0],
        ['304.71', 0.482],
        ['329.76', 0],
        ['329.76', 0],
        ['331.36', 0.484],
        ['355.29', 0],
        ['357.01', 0.487],
        ['382.56', 0],
        ['384.44', 0.495],
        ['410.96', 0],
        ['412.96', 0.494],
        ['439.4', 0],
        ['441.49', 0.483],
        ['468.9', 0],
        ['468.9', 0],
        ['471.28', 0.507],
        ['491.23', 0],
        ['493.57', 0.479],
        ['518.26', 0],
        ['521.34', 0.6],
        ['550.36', 0],
        ['553.62', 0.601],
        ['581.06', 0]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div4'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        width: 450,
        height: 300,
        legend: 'none',
        chartArea: {
            width: "85%",
            height: "60%"
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Сумма',
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: '#FF0000'
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

График получается такой:

[image]

Подскажите как сделать, чтобы в всплывающем окне еще дополнительный текст для каждой точки дописать?

Answer (score 1):

```
function drawChart() {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Year');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
  // A column for custom tooltip content
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['2010', 600,'$600K in our first year!'],
    ['2011', 1500, 'Sunspot activity made this our best year ever!'],
    ['2012', 800, '$800K in 2012.'],
    ['2013', 1000, '$1M in sales last year.']
  ]);

  var options = {
    tooltip: {isHtml: true},
    legend: 'none'
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('col_chart_html_tooltip'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content